# How to style ActionBar differently across multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

My application uses a navigation drawer to let users switch between screens, where each screen is its own fragment. I'd like to style the ActionBar differently for each of the fragments so that each ActionBar is a different color, and contains the appropriate action items in the context of a particular screen. Is this possible? I know fragments can add items to the options menu using `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`, but I'm looking to possibly assign a new menu resource file for each ActionBar.

Each of my fragments look like this:

```
public class myFirstFragment extends Fragment {
View rootview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container, false);
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(1);

}

}
```

and I switch between them with the Navigation Drawer like so:

```
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment objFrag = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFrag = new myFirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFrag = new mySecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFrag = new myThirdFragment();
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFrag)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Tool bar or the old Action bar? If you aren't using the Tool bar then I suggest you start - it's much easier to control the look / placement / menu options in comparison to the Action bar.

Comment: @Daniel Wilson I'm currently using the old Action Bar. Is the task I'm trying to accomplish much easier using Toolbars?

Comment: Yup, it's very easy to programmatically set the color / transparency / layout / content and placement of a Tool bar, it can be treated like a normal view and will probably be defined in the same viewgroup as your R.id.container. This means that it will persist across fragments, but when each fragment is instantiated you can specify properties for the Tool bar. Much of the Action bar is kind of set in stone or very hacky to augment - particularly around your use case of setting the color.dynamically

Comment: I may just go that route then. I need to evaluate whether I can make the jump to API 21+ and go from there. Alternatively I thought I could use many activities instead of fragments, and destroy/create action bars on new activity, but I like the sound of the toolbar approach.

Comment: The tool bar is available in the support library (back to Gingerbread I believe) - the Action bar should really be considered deprecated at his stage, good luck :)